# S-52 symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, chart, s-57

I can load S-57 ENC vector files in .000 format and view the data. I would like to visualise them as the S-52 standard details.

These are nautical charts, some more detail here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_chart_display_and_information_system_(maritime)

I have seen the OpenENV plugin for Grass but can't see how to get this working in QGIS, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement S-52, take a look at the following URL. There is a CD(!) to buy or get with the presentation library. IHO might be of help.

https://www.iho.int/srv1/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=334&Itemid=413&lang=en

The presentation library has a "dai"-file that is a good start. It is a machine readable format for the simplest drawing rules for the different features and their attributes. It also has the icons and even numbers defined in a strange language based on pen-up/pen-down!

The dai-file also reference some "Conditional Symbology Procedures"(CSPs). Those are defines in a (semi-)*human*-readable format in pdf/word files using decision diagrams. It takes a lot of time to implement all of them.

Going forward, S-57 ENC will move to S-101. This is slow moving stuff, so do not hold your breath! It will take some years. S-101 has display procedures encoded in two formats, Lua and XSLT (at least last time I checked). Still complicated, but hopefully a more machine readable and more accessible display standard than S-52.

Good luck!